# Matlab find minimum value by ignoring zero and certain condition

Tags: matlab, conditional-statements, zero, minimum

so i have this data

```
 yi =

    -1
     1
     1
    -2
     4
data=
    1.0000         0    1.0000    0.2000    1.0000    1.0000
         0         0         0    0.5000    1.0000    1.0000
    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000
         0         0         0         0    1.0000         0
    1.0000         0         0         0    1.0000         0
```

and i short that data become like this

sdata =

```
     0    0.2000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000
     0         0         0    0.5000    1.0000    1.0000
1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000
     0         0         0         0         0    1.0000
     0         0         0         0    1.0000    1.0000
```

with this rule

1. if yi >= 0 then output = max row sdata
2. if yi < 0 theris 2 conditions:

   a. if sdata member only 0 and 1 then output = min row sdata =0

   b. if sdata member including number between 0 and 1 then output = min sdata      except zero

so i want to find an output like this

```
output=

  0.2000
  1.0000
  1.0000
  1.0000
       0
  1.0000
```

i still stuck to this point

```
 for i=1:5
        if yi(i)>=0
            output(i)=max(sdata(i,:));
        else
            output(i)=min(sdata(i,:));    
        end;
    end;
    outputnya=output'
```

Comment: is your data only in [0,1]?

Comment: yes its between 0 and 1, including thats number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
else
  minVal = min(sdata(i,sdata(i,:)>0))
  if minVal == 1
    output(i)=min(sdata(i,:));
  else
    output(i) = minVal;
  end;
end;
```

Explanation: `sdata(i,:)>0` returns table of 0 and 1, `sdata(i,sdata(i,:)>0)` returns element which meet specified condition.